# Migrating google sheets api from v3 to v4

Tags: google-sheets-api

I received Google email about migrating to API Google Sheets v4 from v3.  But I am not a developer and who developed this api is not here anymore (and unfortunately no reacheble). Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration). You'll have to provide more information about the specific issues you're having with this if you want more assistance on this.

Comment: Yes I did, but simply I do not know the Google Api development behaviour, so I can't change source or do any other thing. My question is: is there any tool to automatically migrate?

Comment: No, there's no tool like that AFAIK. You would need a developer to do this.